# Technical name for a function that satisfies $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$

Tags: functions, symmetry

Is there a technical name for a function that satisfies the property
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=f(y,x)?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a [symmetric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function)